# TSQL to see when statistics was last updated

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have SQL 2005 server. I am interested in a particular statistics. I can check its last update time manually by right clicking it.

How can I check it using TSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [STATS_DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190330.aspx) function:

> Returns the date of the most recent update for statistics on a table or indexed view.